# How calculate, aligned, offset, and count, for, linux's, direct, storage io, through `O_DIRECT`

Tags: memory-alignment

I need to perform direct-io on a storage device.

This question is also valid for a buffer-pool programmer.

The alignment needed is 4096 bytes,
Im doing

```
// Given: 7,000(count), 14,000(offset)
u64
  aligned_offset = (offset >> 12/* from 4096's width */), // value: 12288
  aligned_offset_remainder = (offset - aligned_offset), // value: 1712
  aligned_count = ((count + 4096) >> 12); // value: 8192
```

The problem is, `aligned_count` should be 12288, to get `(aligned_count + aligned_offset)` as 24576; instead of `(aligned_count/*8192*/ + aligned_offset/*12288*/)`, which gives 20480, which is less than 21,000, hence the required bytes are not read full

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your alligned_count to be 12288 and alligned_count+alligned_offset to 24576 then you should adjust calculation like instead of

```
alligned_count=((count+4096)>>12)
```

you can try this

```
alligned_count=((count+8192)>>12)
```

I see some miss calculation in your code

Comment: isnt this ,just ,patch-work